# outline shows nothing but "The active editor cannot provide outline information" in my extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on a HTML Designer Extension (https://github.com/node-projects/vs-code-designer-addon)

It does display this error in outline view.

What do I need to implement to fill the outline view?
Are there also custom buttons possible in the VSCode outline view?

Comment: maybe you should look in the Language part of the extension docs. Outline is something a Language Server is generating

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[Simple Example to implement VS Code TreeDataProvider with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534723/simple-example-to-implement-vs-code-treedataprovider-with-json-data)

and this example:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample

with them I could create my own Tree, but I wanted to fill the outline view

Comment: found this: https://github.com/ChaunceyKiwi/json-tree-view
maybe this helps me